# Multiple Stopwatch App

Tags: android, kotlin

I was fed up with the default alarm clock when doing laundry. The washing machine is in the basement and takes different time depending on the choosen program. The stopwatch has to be configured for every use and can run only one instance (we also have a tumble dryer). The alarm itself is only for fixed times, not for durations, so I figured I write my own app for this.

The app is working in itself, you can create new 'templates' consisting of a name and duration. You can modify or delete them afterwards. You can start a 'reminder' by tapping one template. Once the time is due a notification is send.

Here is my github where the complete project can be seen: [https://github.com/totoMauz/Reminder](https://github.com/totoMauz/Reminder/tree/a00006cbd5558a98836c0f95f2bdd3b29978b387)

I'm looking for feedback on the following:

- My Kotlin usage as it's my first project
- Any misuse of Android patterns, as it's my first app

I'm unhappy with the use of the companion objects like this:

```
class MaintainReminderActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        const val TOKEN = "MaintainReminder"
        val INTENTS: MutableList<Intent> = ArrayList()
    }
    ...
}
```

And one usage of the INTENTS and why it's still static:

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        buildNotification(context, intent)
        MaintainReminderActivity.INTENTS.remove(intent)
    }
}
```

I tried to replace it with Intents and startActivity(ForResult) but somehow couldn't make it work from inside the BroadcastReceiver...

Anotherthing that is bugging me is, that the ActionMode is only showing the Icon, despite the title beeing in the XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/template_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/delete"
        android:title="@string/action_mode_template_delete" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/template_edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/edit"
        android:title="@string/action_mode_template_edit" />
</menu>
```

The ActionMode is invoked like this:

```
class MaintainTemplatesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    ...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maintain_templates)
        loadTemplates()

        viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        viewAdapter = TemplateAdapter(ITEMS)

        (viewAdapter as TemplateAdapter).apply {
            onItemClick = { reminder: Reminder ->
                triggerAlarm(reminder)
            }
            onLongItemClick = { reminder: Reminder ->
                startActionMode(TemplateActionModeCallback(reminder, this@MaintainTemplatesActivity), ActionMode.TYPE_PRIMARY)
                true
            }
        }
        recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvTemplates).apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = viewManager
            adapter = viewAdapter
        }
    }
    ....
}

class TemplateActionModeCallback(val reminder: Reminder, private val templateActivity: MaintainTemplatesActivity) : ActionMode.Callback {
    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode, item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.template_delete -> {
                templateActivity.deleteTemplate(reminder)
                mode.finish()
                true
            }
            R.id.template_edit -> {
                templateActivity.deleteTemplate(reminder)

                val intent = Intent(templateActivity.applicationContext, TemplateActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_REMINDER, reminder.name)
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DURATION, reminder.duration)
                templateActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
                mode.finish()
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
        val inflater = mode.menuInflater
        inflater?.inflate(R.menu.template_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode) {}
}
```